# All possible options for automating a task (in my case, a search index update)

Tags: c#, asp.net, automation, build-automation

I have a ASP.NET website running on Server 2003 with SQL-Server as database.

I have two tasks that I want to automate on daily basis.

1) Update the Lucene search index file

2) Update the profile pic of all user from LDAP server

I have both codes in aspx pages but I want them to run daily at midnight or 4 am in the morning or something like that. I havent done any automation before so I am clueless. So
my question is...

**What are my options?**

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got some options:

There is this on Code Project [Simulate a Windows Service using ASP.NET to run scheduled jobs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc)

You can write your own Windows service.

You can go the commercial route and use a web based scheduler. Two popular ones are:

[web.scheduler](http://scheduler.codeeffects.com/) and [web based cron](http://webbasedcron.com/)

Another option is to create a Windows scheduled task. When the task fires off, you can have it hit a page that runs the logic you wish to perform. Here's a linked solution on SO: [Recommended method for loading a URL via a scheduled task on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987345/recommended-method-for-loading-a-url-via-a-scheduled-task-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for automation within your asp.net web application, consider [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) as a good free, open source solution.  We've been using it to automate maintenance tasks and are quite happy with the results.