# How to open web page periodically, using Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, html

I need to open one web page periodically, using Task Scheduler.

On Linux I can run crontab job to do that, but this time I have to do on Windows XP.

Can you help me how is it possible to achieve it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommended method for loading a URL via a scheduled task on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987345/recommended-method-for-loading-a-url-via-a-scheduled-task-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a URL using Windows Task Scheduler, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12081686/172163). However, there are other options like scheduling tool [ATrigger](http://atrigger.com).

**Disclaimer**: I was among builders of ATrigger. freeware, not commercial.