# application configuration code in asp.net mvc appliction_start

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Right now I have some code which needs to be executed only once in the application life cycle. I have that code in application_start event but this slows down my first request has there is some heavy configuration to be done.

Is there any alternative to this? Is it possible to execute some logic during the deployment process?

Comment: Just force the very first request just after the deployment.

Comment: Yes.That is one way of doing it. I was just wondering if that is the only way...

Comment: It is just how you think about it. Think that the first initial request forced by you is a part of the deployment process. Your users will not notice as they are in after deployment completes.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen every time your app pool recycles.  So if you app pool recycle once a day the first request following the recycle will be slow.  What I have done to mitigate this issue is to have a script hit the web site right after the app recycles to take the initial performance hit instead of an end user.

Comment: That sounds interesting. Can I know how to write such a script?

Comment: I use https://github.com/kennethscott/ASP.NET-Site-Warmup but you could use a windows scheduled task to do it as a test first see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987345/recommended-method-for-loading-a-url-via-a-scheduled-task-on-windows for an example.

Comment: Were you able to get the app to warm up?