# Auto closure of process in task manager using php on server

Tags: php, joomla2.5

How to auto closure of process in task manager using php on server?

I have use the below script for auto closing of  IE browser tab while running cron using task manager,

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var win = window.open("","_self"); /* url = "" or "about:blank"; target="_self" */
    win.close();
</script>
```

But `IEexplorer.exe` process not ending in task manager on server side but its ending on local host.

Can anyone explain how to end the process or auto close the IE tab on server using php?

Comment: IE on a server? Never heared about that

Comment: Why is IE opened on the server?

Comment: We have maintains separate production server for website.

Comment: @Anigel: Im running cron URL(http://example.com/index.php?option=com_sample&view=cron&task=cronexcelreport) using ieexplorer.exe in task scheduler.

Comment: Simple answer, Don't open the url in IE just request url directly instead of opening up IE and requesting the url in IE. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987345/recommended-method-for-loading-a-url-via-a-scheduled-task-on-windows

Comment: Im have given cron as "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://example.com/index.php?option=com_sample&view=cron&task=cronexcelreport" .Every day I auto scheduled to run cron, and each time ieexplorer.exe runs. But i need to close that ieexplorer.exe after ending of process every day.